# Conversion of year column into respective years columns

Tags: python, pandas

[[[https://github.com/Shristigithub/Population/blob/master/population.csv]]](https://github.com/Shristigithub/Population/blob/master/population.csv)[1](https://github.com/Shristigithub/Population/blob/master/population.csv)
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bf64A.png][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6zVZ.png)

Please help me to get one country name and all the years columns separately.

i want output to look something like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6zVZ.png)

Comment: Please don't share images of data, share a sample of the data itself

Comment: Do you need [pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe)?

Comment: Years with same country names? You mean like this: Arab world, 1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, .... ?

Comment: Please show expected output data

Comment: yes you are correct i want the output as you have said. @Sherzod

Comment: @jezrael It was actually pivot. I wasnot aware about pivot.Thank you. I got my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'id':['a','a','b','c','c'], 
  'words':['asd','rtr','s','rrtttt','dsfd']})
print(df)

zet = df.groupby('id')['words'].apply(','.join)
print(zet)
```

Output:

```
  id   words
0  a     asd
1  a     rtr
2  b       s
3  c  rrtttt
4  c    dsfd


id
a        asd,rtr
b              s
c    rrtttt,dsfd
Name: words, dtype: object
```

In your case maybe something like this:

```
sorted_output = df.groupby('coutry_name')['years'].apply(','.join)
```

Comment: Values not in a same column but different columns. @Sherzod

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, hope this will help.

Consider your data frame to be like this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [1,2,34,6,7,8,9],'values':[123,3454,6734,123,45,234,123]})
```

So df will be like:

```
    Date    values
0     1     123
1     2     3454
2     34    6734
3     6     123
4     7     45
5     8     234
6     9     123
```

Now first take transpose and then set column value, as shown below:

```
df = df.transpose()
df.columns= df.iloc[0]
df
```

Ouput will be:

```
Date    1        2       34     6        7    8     9    <--- These are now columns headers
Date    1        2       34     6        7    8     9       
values  123     3454    6734    123     45  234     123
```